# cannot subscript of type [String]

Tags: arrays, swift, subscript

i get this error on:

```
        cell.naamItem = VragenInformatie[indexPath.section][indexPath.row][0]
```

i have this in the same class:

```
    var VragenInformatie: [[[String]]] = [[[]]]
```

and this is how the array looks like:

```
var VragenInformatie: [[[String]]] = [[["Spelletjeskamer",""],["Keuken",""],["Garage",""],["Binnenplaats",""],["Zitkamer",""],["Slaapkamer",""],["Studeerkamer",""],["Eetkamer",""],["Badkamer",""]],[["De Wit",""],["Pimpel",""],["Blaauw van Draet",""],["Roodhart",""],["Groenewoud",""],["Van Geelen",""]],[["Loden pijp",""],["Pistool",""],["Engelse sleutel",""],["Dolk",""],["Touw",""],["Kandelaar",""]]]
```

i don't really no what the problem is here neither do i know what subscript really means

could someone give some advise?

Comment: What is the error message? The result of the expression on the right side is a `String`. Is `naamItem` also a `String`?

Comment: Is `cell.naamItem` a String ?

Comment: That's a lot of `[[[` & `]]]`. LISP nostalgia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet your `naamItem` is a UILabel or something like that, and you forgot to append the '.text'. If my theory is true, your code should look something like this:

```
cell.naamItem.text = VragenInformatie[indexPath.section][indexPath.row][0]
```

In any other case where the `naamItem` is NOT an UILabel, UITextView or UITextField, you should make sure the `naamItem` is of type `String`.